# Pushing Array of object from react to mongodb+express server issue

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm store array of object but it is giving mer following error.

(node:87929) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Place validation failed: placesToVisit: Cast to embedded failed for value "[{"name":"xczc","location":"zczxc","description":"czxczx"}]" (type string) at path "placesToVisit" because of "ObjectParameterError"

here is my schema:

```html
placesToVisit: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter the place's name"],
      },
      description:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter the place's description"],
      },
      location:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter the place's location"],
      }
    },
  ],
```

here is my contoller:

```html
exports.createPlace = async (req, res) => {
  
  try {
    const newPlace = await new Place({
    
     placesToVisit:req.body.placesToVisit,
    
    });
    newPlace.save()
    debugger
    res.status(201).json({
        success:true,
        message:"Place Created Successfully",
        newPlace
    })
  } catch (error) {
     return res.status(500).json({
          success:false,
          error:error.message
      })
  }
};
```

here is my formdata structure:

```html
data.append("placesToVisit",JSON.stringify(values.placesToVisit))
```

here is ss of yaload
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must convert the string to an array:

```js
placesToVisit: JSON.parse(req.body.placesToVisit),
```